# Deleting Data with Hibernate with several EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity that can reference another object of the same entity. When I want to delete the object in the database I can get a ConstraintViolation. Therefore I first search for Entities that have a reference of the object to delete and set the value to null. I do this with the criteriaBuilder and do a bulk update. 
Afterwards I delete the entity. At the next select statement I got the error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance
```

It could be that I use two different instances of the entityManager. The first one does the bulk update and the second one deletes the entity. 
So what happens when the second entityManager does a flush? Are also the data from the first entityManager changed in the database? And if so, in which order are the statements in the database executed?
Or do I do another mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: you should use cascadeType

Comment: I normally want to get the ConstraintViolation because it should not be able to delete such data. But in that special case it should be allowed to remove the data from the database.
But just to learn something: which cascadeType would be the one to choose?

Comment: you can use CascadeType.ALL

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the bulk update. The hibernate cache does not know about the changes in the database. Therefore the referenced entity in the cache is not equivalent to the database and it crashes. 
I first have to refresh the referenced entity and then it works. Alternatively i have to change the bulk update into a "normal" update where i load all the entities from the database and set the property to change to null.